# database query on month, day, year columns

Tags: mysql

I have database records with  month[int,2], day[int,2] and year[int,4] columns holding data such as 10, 25 and 2019. The oldest entry has month, day and year column entries of 10, 25, and 2019.

I'm trying to `SELECT` records from-to specific dates but this is not working, returns zero records.

```
SELECT * FROM site_stats 
WHERE ( (month>=10 AND day>=25 AND year>=2019) AND (month<=11 AND day<=01 AND year<=2019) )
```

I thought this would have but it does not. It returns all but 7 records.They have a month 11 and day 1:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM site_stats WHERE (month>=10 AND day>=25 AND year>=2019)
```

This works to get all 791 records. I know I don't need the `WHERE` clause, I just used it to see results.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM site_stats WHERE (month>=10 AND day>=1 AND year>=2019)
```

Comment: You can do this more easily with a single `DateTime` column and using the SQL `BETWEEN` keyword. You can do the 2nd where with the same `DateTime` column and a standard comparison poerator.

Answer (score 1):

Your query can't match records because you check for `day` greater than 25 and lower than 1.

You can use the following solution:

```
SELECT * FROM site_stats
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', `year`, `month`, `day`), '%Y-%c-%e') BETWEEN '2019-10-25' AND '2019-11-01'
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d2b0a56701940636ccca47dcb2beb2c2)

This query is using [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to get a date value from your tree columns (`year`, `month` and `day`). Now you can simply use `BETWEEN` to check the date with your period of time (start: `2019-10-25`; end: `2019-11-01`).

You can also change your table and replace the columns (with date parts) with a `DATE` column.

Comment: Thanks very much, that works great! While changing the table may create a simpler querying option, it's not the answer to my question. But your provided solution was, so thanks again.